# How to fix AFTER UPDATE Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I created a User Point system for my website. The table looks like this:

```
user_id   name    article    gallery    description    total
------------------------------------------------------------
1         joe      7          3          0             10
2         hary     3          5          5             13
3         ana      1          1          2             4
```

I need an AFTER UPDATE trigger that will make the update SUM in the column total when the value changes in the column, article, gallery or description

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER total_trg
AFTER UPDATE point_system FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE point_system SET total = (article + gallery + description) FROM point_system WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id;        
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

This trigger does not work. Why?

Comment: mysql does not allow the update trigger of a table to update the same table

Comment: Thank you. I found a solution without trigger

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify a table's contents from a trigger on that table (except for the row the trigger is operating on, but not in that way); in this case, what you need is a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger, in which you would just

`SET NEW.total = NEW.article + NEW.gallery + NEW.description;`

You use `NEW` and `OLD` to access (and modify in BEFORE triggers) the field values of the row responsible for the trigger firing.

Comment: So, I need only to change SET line. Did I understand it well?

Comment: It needs to be a `BEFORE UPDATE` as well; `AFTER` is too late to change the value.

Comment: Thanks, I will try

Comment: I tried and did not work. I found a solution without trigger. Thanks anyway.